# Run command on Pi based on ping result

Tags: python-2.x, ping

I am very new to this stuff. Trying to see if anyone has accomplished what I am looking to do.

I would like to have a ping to my android phone running on my Raspberry Pi. When it gets a response I want the Pi to run a command (turn on lights etc). My goal is to have the lights turn on as soon as I get home and my android phone is ping-able. Then eventually I want to create something that does the same after ping is lost for an hour.

I have seen people do similar things for external URLs with code below. Any ideas?

```
import socket
from urllib2 import urlopen, URLError, HTTPError

socket.setdefaulttimeout( 23 )  # timeout in seconds

url = 'http://google.com/'
try :
    response = urlopen( url )
except HTTPError, e:
    print 'The server couldn\'t fulfill the request. Reason:', str(e.code)
except URLError, e:
    print 'We failed to reach a server. Reason:', str(e.reason)
else :
    html = response.read()
    print 'got response!'
    # do something, turn the light on/off or whatever
```

Comment: your question has nothing to do with the RPi ... it is a Python programming problem

Comment: Yeah that should be obvious... Yet I am running it on a Pi. More info the better.

Comment: why don't you run this code on a Mac, then you can engage Apple technical support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following Python will ping an IP address on your network:

```
import os

ip = '10.0.0.38'

if os.system('ping -c 1 '+ip) == 0:
    print('found')
else:
    print('not found')
```

Comment: Thanks! I think that is close to what I am looking for. Been trying to accomplish this a few different ways. When I tried it earlier I At first used Cron to run this script periodically (ping -c 1 192.168.86.66 &> /dev/null && /var/www/rfoutlet/codesend 98682 -l 173 -p 0 || /var/www/rfoutlet/codesend 87862 -l 173 -p 0). Goal is to have the main light turn on when I get home, and then off as soon as I leave. My setup is based on a No-Internet concept. I don't want to rely on a connection when I could just automate things in different ways without it.